# What's the difference between inventory_hostname and ansible_hostname

Tags: ansible

All I could find was this from [the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts):

> Additionally, `inventory_hostname` is the name of the hostname as configured in Ansible’s inventory host file. This can be useful for when you don’t want to rely on the discovered hostname `ansible_hostname` or for other mysterious reasons. If you have a long FQDN, `inventory_hostname_short` also contains the part up to the first period, without the rest of the domain.

Is there any actual difference between `inventory_hostname` and `ansible_hostname` variables in Ansible? If so, then which one should I use and when?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

- `inventory_hostname` - As configured in the ansible inventory file (eg: `/etc/ansible/hosts`). It can be an IP address or a name that can be resolved by the DNS
- `ansible_hostname` - As discovered by `ansible`. Ansible logs into the host via `ssh` and gathers some facts. As part of the fact, it also discovers its hostname which is stored in `ansible_hostname`.

#### Which one should you use?

`hostvars` is a dictionary which has an entry for each inventory host. If you want to access host information, you need to use the `inventory_hostname`. If you want to use/print the name of the host as configured on the host, you should use `ansible_hostname` since most likely the IP will be used in the inventory file.

**Important**: To use `ansible_hostname`, you need to gather facts:

```
gather_facts: true
```

Otherwise, you will get a message that `ansible_hostname` is not defined.

```
"ansible_hostname": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

Try this with one host to understand the differences

```
  tasks:
    - debug: var=inventory_hostname
    - debug: var=ansible_hostname
    - debug: var=hostvars
```

Comment: `inventory_hostname` is an arbitrary name you set in inventory file. It doesn't need to be resolvable by DNS.

Comment: But in that case you have to set `ansible_host` right?

Comment: @lost yes, or set up ssh (~/.ssh/config) so it'll know how to connect there by name