# How to ensure that an Ansible command is run only once

Tags: ansible

In my Ansible setup I use some API calls that can only be run once. But how do I ensure that a command is run only once?
I have tried the following code but it does not work:

```
    name: network config | Create MAAS default space
    block:
      - name: Create Space
        command: 'maas {{ maas__profile }} spaces create name=default'
        register: default_space_created_status
      - name: Set status
        set_fact:
          default_space_created_status
    when: not default_space_created_status.changed
```

I've also tried using a run_once flag, but this doesn't work either. The command can be run multiple times.

Edit: The proposed solution of using 'ansible_hostname == ansible_play_hosts[0]', I can't make it work either.

Comment: There is a `run_once` flag. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the following:
        - name: network config | Create MAAS default space
          command: 'maas {{ maas__profile }} spaces create name=default'
          run_once: true

But this doesn't work either. The command is run multiple times.

Comment: What error message do you see with my solution?

Comment: There is just a standard error message from the MAAS server stating that a space with that name already exists, since unfortunately the command can be run more than once.

Comment: Since you already tried to execute that command, doesn't it stand to reason that *any* subsequent trial, even executed only *once* would trigger the error "a space with that name already exists"?

Comment: In general, I appreciate that my Ansible roles are made to work in an idempotent way. Do you think this is a wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

The [directive `run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) might not be exactly what you need, since it will apply all results and facts to all the hosts in the same batch.

Try instead, [using ansible_hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908718/6309) `when: ansible_hostname == ansible_play_hosts[0]` (assuming you have gathered facts first, `gather_facts: True`)

```
name: network config | Create MAAS default space
    block:
      - name: Create Space
        command: 'maas {{ maas__profile }} spaces create name=default'
        register: default_space_created_status
      - name: Set status
        set_fact:
          default_space_created_status
    when: ansible_hostname == ansible_play_hosts[0]
```