# ansible jinja template hostvars can not get ansible_host

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to iterate over hostvars in an ansible playbook and it appears to be working just fine to several hostvars, except the one I need: ansible_host

If I try:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
  server {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host] }}  
{% endfor %}
```

It outputs this for each server:
server server2 {'ansible_verbosity': 0,, '...  'ansible_check_mode': False, 'ansible_run_tags': [u'all'], 'ansible_skip_tags': [], u'ansible_host': u'10.192.11.17', 'ansible_version': {'major': 2, 'full': '2.9.11', 'string': '2.9.11', 'minor': 9, 'revision': 11}}

Which holds all vars.

Now If I try

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
  server {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host]['verbosity'] }}  
{% endfor %}
```

it will get me the ansible_verbosity just fine. But I can not find a way to get the ansible_host

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
  server {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_host'] }}  
{% endfor %}
```

I think the problem maybe related to the fact ansible_host is a unicode var ( u'ansible_host' ). I say that because the other 2 unicode vars fails with the same problem while all the others work just fine.

Any idea how to get that var?

Comment: What's the use-case? Is there any practical reason `ansible_host` should be always included in `hostvars`?

Comment: I've been told these servers must not have an entry on DNS. Not my call.

Answer (score 3):

Q: **"*hostvars can not get ansible_host*"**

A: `ansible_host` is not included in `hostvars` if it is not explicitly declared. `ansible_host` is a [Connection variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables). It is used, for example, as a parameter of the `ssh connection plugin` (see `ansible-doc -t connection ssh`). It is needed if `inventory_hostname` does not resolve. Very probably, any of your hosts don't have an `ansible_host` explicitly set. This is causing the problem. If `ansible_host` is not explicitly declared its value is set to `inventory_hostname`.

For example

```sh
shell > grep test_11 hosts
test_11
```

```yaml
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_host']
    - debug:
        var: ansible_host
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_host']: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  ansible_host: test_11
```

---

If you declare `ansible_host`, for example, in the inventory

```sh
shell > grep test_11 hosts
test_11 ansible_host=10.1.0.61
```

the same playbook gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_host']: 10.1.0.61

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  ansible_host: 10.1.0.61
```

---

- See [Inventory aliases](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-aliases)
- Quoting [Connection variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables)

> ansible_host: The ip/name of the target host to use instead of inventory_hostname.

- See also [What's the difference between inventory_hostname and ansible_hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908067/whats-the-difference-between-inventory-hostname-and-ansible-hostname)

---

A quick solution to the problem might be defaulting to `inventory_hostname`, assuming `ansible_host` is not needed, i.e. `inventory_hostname` resolves. For example

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
  server {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_host']|default(host) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. You were right. One of the hosts did not have its ansible_host defined. Thank you!