# Ansible playbook with "replace" and "after" marching lines that are not directly after

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

A simple playbook code intended to update dhcpcd

```yaml
---
- name: Set ES heap min
  hosts: local

  tasks:
    - name: test task
      replace:
        path: /home/pedro/ansible_test/test.conf
        after: 'interface eth0'
        regexp: '^static ip_address=[0-9 ]*\.[0-9 ]*\.[0-9 ]*\.[0-9 ]*\/[0-9 ]*'
        replace: "static ip_address={{ ip_address }}/24"
        backup: yes
```

The idea is to update an IP of a particular interface (in this case eth0)
(note my regex needs improvement but has no effect on what is happening)

So it works OK as log as the other interface is commented out, else it will update the line `static ip_address=` in all interfaces that as not commented out.

test file:

```
# Example static IP configuration:
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.390/24
static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 #8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.30/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
```

If like above then profile other than eth0 will not be touched which is desired. However if the line `#static ip_address=192.168.1.30/2` would be commented, this line would be also modified, which is undesired.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-after) one gets the idea that the line that has "interface eth0" will be identified and ONLY the line with the matching regex will be modified, but that does not seem to be true.

example of result after running with Uncommented line:

```
# Example static IP configuration:
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.390/24
static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 #8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.390/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I misinterpreting the documentation, or is this not intended to work as I described, is there a bug ?

Please help me understand

I am running Ansible 1.9 with python 3.8:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/pedro/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Comment: `interface eth0` is the second line in your file. As very clearly explained in the documentation, anything that matches your regex after that line will be replaced which is very precisely the behavior you describe. You options are (non exhaustive list) 1) combine using `before` to further restrain where modifications are applied 2) don't use replace and try your luck with [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html)which is maybe more appropriate to your use case 3) use a template.

Comment: @Zeitounator not sure if I agree with documentation  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-after clearly stated : ``` If specified, only content after this match will be replaced/removed. ``` in combination with the words ONLY suggests that it will match ONLY  regex AFTER the line ``` interface eth0   ``` and not the other non matching ones. That is why I posted this.I think its a bug. But will try your suggestions.using ```lineinfile```

Comment: `This module will replace all instances of a pattern within a file.` .... and about the `after` option: `If specified, only content after this match will be replaced/removed.` What is unclear with that ? => all replacements will be made after `after` match.

Comment: @Zeitounator I see now. It is in tiny letters all the way on top above the BIG bold module name and description. I completely missed it. Thanks! Appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your use case that you like to update the entry of the first occurrence of `static ip_address=` only. As already mentioned in the comments, I've found the approach with `lineinfile` working to [replace first occurrence of certain expression in file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70247616/6771046) `dhcpcd.conf`.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    IP_ADDRESS: "192.0.2.0/24"

  tasks:

  - name: Update IP for eth0
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/dhcpcd.conf
      regexp: '^static ip_address=[0-9 ]*\.[0-9 ]*\.[0-9 ]*\.[0-9 ]*\/[0-9 ]*'
      line: "static ip_address={{ IP_ADDRESS }}"
      firstmatch: true
      state: present
      backup: true
```